# Any experience on the 2N7002 MOSFET for logic level working at 3.3 V?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic

I know that the 2N7002 is nominally a 5V MOSFET (probably it was designed at 10V and then rated at 5V?). Also Nexperia is cheating and has 'variants' on the 7002 (better VGSth on some)

However with the current part shortage discrete small signal mosfets are nowhere to be found (big quantities only on the 7002 and the 138, essentially). Either that or the micro packages.

The question is: the datasheet states a VGSth of max 2.5V at Id=0.25mA. I need these MOSFETs to mass-pull reset lines of 3.3V parts. Given that the VGS guaranteed is 2.65V (from the LVCMOS specs) and the pullups are 10k to 47k it *should* be able to pull them down successfully. A BJT *could* be an alternative but I'm still investigating on how many microamps I have for the drive (micropower supervisor/watchdog, by the way)

I reckon that for this to not work it will have to:

- Have a weak gate drive (2.65V is the minimum)
- MOSFET with hard gate (2.5V maximum)
- Receiving part really hard to reset (990mV maximum for zero logic level)
- Really cold environment raises the VGSth but this is not an issue

So I think it should be pretty reliable. Is there some other phenomena I missed or this should work as designed?

Comment: I've been using the 2N7002 as my go-to jellybean transistor for 3V3 logic stuff for years, in several industrial products. Not a single time has there been an issue related to the gate voltage of these transistors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I expected that by calculations but the output curve on the datasheet is not helping since it's officially a 'power' part and the diagram goes up to 3A (which is silly since the maximum pulsed is about 1A)

Comment: We use 2306 MOSFETs by the billions.   I.e.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.vishay.com/docs/70827/70827.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiws9mZk8j0AhX2rHIEHXxnCnMQFnoECCgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw08B411799thudGmx4_IKxd

Comment: @KyleB we have the 2308 as a favorite but not for logic levels: great for relays, fans and such smaller loads

Answer (score 2):

You’d probably get away with it, but BSS138 is a much better fit (many manufacturers guarantee Rds(on) with 2.5 or 2.75V drive and there is reasonable availability and price.

Comment: That was *exactly* my second choice, the 138 is widely available